# Changing Column Heading CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am currently trying to change the headings of the file I am creating. The code I am using is as follows;

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys
import glob
path = "C:\\Users\\cam19\\Desktop\\Test1\\*.csv"
list_=[]
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype=None, low_memory=False)
    output = (df['logid'].value_counts())
    list_.append(output)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = pd.concat(list_, axis=1)
    df2.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Basically I am looping through a file directory and extracting data from each file. Using this is outputs the following image;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/roER1.jpg

All i want to do it change the columns names from 'logid' to the file name it is currently searching but I am not sure how to do this. Any help is great! Thanks.

Comment: You create a DataFrame `df` but never use it. It this intentional? The last two lines of your code are executed in the loop. Is this intentional?

Comment: The dataframe was left over from some previous code, ignore that. Last two lines was intentional; however, upon reviewing I could just update list_, no need to constantly write the new file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending the values try to append values by creating the dataframe and setting the column i.e

```
output = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].value_counts())
output.columns = [os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]]
list_.append(output)
```

Changes in the code in the question

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys
import glob
path = "C:\\Users\\cam19\\Desktop\\Test1\\*.csv"
list_=[]

for fname in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    output = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].value_counts())
    output.columns = [os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]]
    list_.append(output)


df2 = pd.concat(list_, axis=1)
df2.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This gives me invalid syntax error but I am completely unsure as to why.

Comment: Sorry there was a parenthesis missing in the `list_.append` line.

Comment: It only seems to be appending the list to the name now. Such that I have this, but no data anymore. http://imgur.com/a/LE7OS

Comment: If I add the line list_.append(output) I can get the data + the cloumn header; however, the column header is the header of the next column whereas the header of the column of data remains as 'logid'

Comment: Its working with the demo data I have. Do you want the value_counts? or values ?

Comment: I would like the value_counts

Comment: If I add your line to my code and leave my code as it is, this is what I get;
http://imgur.com/a/LE7OS. I would like the OCYSXH header to replace the logid header.

Comment: Updated my answer. You need the values from value counts and then set the columns hope it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151187/discussion-between-cameron-and-bharath-shetty).